# Add CleanContext to sphinx_build.py

Tags: waf

I am using the a waf-tool to build sphinx documentation from GitHub (see [here](https://github.com/named-data/ndn-tools/blob/master/.waf-tools/sphinx_build.py)).

How can I add a command like `clean_sphinx`  to that script? I have to add the CleanContext to it, but I do not get how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, binding a command to a specific context is easy, just inherit from this context:

```py
from waflib.Build import CleanContext

class my_dummy_tmp_class_name(CleanContext):
    cmd = "clean_sphinx"
    fun = "my_sphinx_clean_function"
```

You can have a look at the [waf book §7.2.2](https://waf.io/book/#_custom_build_outputs): Configuration sets for variants. It explains how to add variant commands to all contexts.